# CSS Dropdown Menu error and doesn't show

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

This is supposedly a navigation of a dropdown menu using CSS3.
However my problem is that the dropdown menu doesn't show. And personally, I get confused with using ul li, but I think I got it right. But there still seems to be a problem.
I still consider myself a beginner, so I would really appreciate some help.

Here is the html code

```
  <div id="nav" class="nav"> 
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Magazines</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Library Resources</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">PUBLISH</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and my css,

```
 .nav {
width: 800px;
height: 70px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 65px;
left: 136px;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
z-index: 900;
overflow: visible;
}





.nav ul {

padding: 0 30px;
border-radius: 10px;  
list-style: none;
position:relative;
width: 600px;
display: inline-table;
}

.nav ul:after {
    content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
}

.nav ul ul {
display: none;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    z-index: 1000;
    opacity: 1;
}

.nav ul li:hover > ul li {
    display: block;
            overflow: visible;
            padding: 0;
}


.nav ul li {
float: left;
opacity: 1;
z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
}   

.nav ul li:hover {
    background: #ffa32f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffae48 0%, #ffa32f 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffae48 0%, #ffa32f 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffae48 0%,#ffa32f 40%);
    height: 80px;
    opacity: .8;
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;
        z-index: 1000;
}
    .nav ul li:hover a {
        color: #fff;
    }

.nav ul li a {
    display: block; padding: 15px 12px;
    color: #000; text-decoration: none;
}

.active{
  color: #ffffff;
    background: #ffa32f;
    background: linear-gradient(top, #ffae48 0%, #ffa32f 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffae48 0%, #ffa32f 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffae48 0%,#ffa32f 40%);
    height: 50px;
    z-index: -1000;
}
```

Why doesn't the dropdown box show?
Here is the you can see more of the code with preview HERE http://jsfiddle.net/6a8Qp/2/

Please do tell me where I am wrong. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that your dropdown ul is not within your parent items li

Change it to:

```
<div id="nav" class="nav"> 
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Magazines</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Library Resources</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
<li><a href="#">PUBLISH</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
<li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
<li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, specially for the fast response. It is very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `</li>` after `<a>` of products.
i.e.

```
<li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
```

instead of

```
<li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
```

and put ending `</li>` tag after `<ul>` tag completes within that `<li>`

```
<li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Magazines</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Library Resources</a></li>
       </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your corrected css and HTML code. **[FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/6a8Qp/11/)**

**css**

```
.nav {
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: 0px;                     
    margin-top: 0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight:500;
    margin:0 auto;
    }
.nav ul {
    padding:0 30px;
    border-radius:10px; 
    line-height:47px; 
    background-color:#67b01a;
    height:47px;
    }
.nav ul li {
    float:left; 
    position:relative;
    } 
.nav ul li a {
    display:block; 
    padding:0 12px;
    color: #000; 
    text-decoration:none;
    }   
.nav ul li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
    background:#ffa32f;
    /*background: linear-gradient(top, #ffae48 0%, #ffa32f 40%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffae48 0%, #ffa32f 40%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffae48 0%,#ffa32f 40%);
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -webkit-transition: opacity .5s linear;*/
    }
.nav ul li ul {
    display:none;
    background-color:#ffa432;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:47px;
    width:400px;
    padding:0 30px;
    }
.nav ul li ul li {
    float:left;
    }
.nav ul li ul li a {
    background-color:#e1a62b;
    color:#fff;
    }
.nav ul li ul li:hover a,
.nav ul li ul li a.active {
    background-color:#e1891c;
    color:#fff;
    /*opacity:1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=1);
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1.0s linear;*/
    }   
.nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML STRUCURE**

```
<div id="nav" class="nav"> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Magazines</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Library Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
        <li><a href="#">RESOURCES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PUBLISH</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```